# Get selected item in a ListItem ContextMenu

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contextmenu

I have a ListView which creates a ContextMenu on long press of one of its elements. How do I find the element that was selected in the ListView that created this context menu (not the selected MenuItem)? Here is my code:

```
list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, final View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Actions");
        android.view.MenuItem remove = menu.add("Remove");
        final int selectedItem = ((ListView)v).getSelectedItemPosition();
        remove.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {   
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(android.view.MenuItem item) {
                doSomething(listAdapter.getItem(selectedItem)); // NPE here
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Please note that I do not want the item that was selected from the context menu, but the ListView item that triggered this context menu instead.

Comment: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/05/context-menu-android-developer-tutorial.html